# Do some Litvaks in Jerusalem have a minhag of long payos?

Tags: minhag, clothing, yerushalayim-jerusalem, payot-sideburns

Do some Litvaks in Jerusalem have a minhag of long payos? For example, [Rav Azriel Auerbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezriel_Auerbach) has long curled payos even though he is Litvish.

Comment: 'long' is subjective. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Tlo6aRTiCc

Comment: Well you seem to have answered your question.

Comment: Define "Litvaks"! Rav Ezriel's paternal grandfather hailed from Poland, though his great-grandfather was from Tzefat. Rav Ezriel is hardly a "Litvak"... (trace his lineage from  his brother's Wikipedia page.)

Comment: For almost any value of X and Y, the question "do some Jews of type X do practice Y?" is invariably true